# Adding a description to a css image slideshow

Tags: html, css

I recently created a css slideshow based on animation,my question how should i add a description  to those images that changes with every image that rotates.
Here is the code:

### Html

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>

<img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/giresources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt>
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt>
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg" alt>
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt>
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg" alt>
</figure>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
 0% { left: 0%; }
 20% { left: 0%; }
 25% { left: -100%; }
 45% { left: -100%; }
 50% { left: -200%; }
 70% { left: -200%; }
 75% { left: -300%; }
 95% { left: -300%; }
 100% { left: -400%; }
}

@keyframes slidy {
 0% { left: 0%; }
 20% { left: 0%; }
 25% { left: -100%; }
 45% { left: -100%; }
 50% { left: -200%; }
 70% { left: -200%; }
 75% { left: -300%; }
 95% { left: -300%; }
 100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden;
 height:100%;
}
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
 position: relative;
 width: 500%;
 margin: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 0;
 -webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  }
```

[Here is the fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/dao0xnkk/)

My problem is how should i sincronize the description with the image, i would use transitions but i dont know how should i queue the transitions for the descriptions...
P.S Sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Where are the descriptions?

Comment: You are very close. Just wrap each img separately with div etc. than you can add description label inside outer image div.

Comment: that is what i want to add, and i cant fid the right way to do this, the problem i face is how should i make , that the right decriptions aper under the right image , those descriptions should fade in  under hover or when the image changes.I was thinking to make an animation that is doing this  for every  image, but i dont know how to that since you cant animate the display property .

Comment: Thank you @Taras Kumpanenko, thats a good ideea  i will try it and return with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/dao0xnkk/1/)

The idea being it's a whole div that animated not just the image.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt />
      <span class="caption">Slide number 01</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt>
      <span class="caption">Slide number 02</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg" alt>
      <span class="caption">Slide number 03</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt>
      <span class="caption">Slide number 04</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg" alt>
      <span class="caption">Slide number 05</span>
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

div#slider figure .slide {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}

div#slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
}

div#slider figure .caption {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
```

Comment: Dude ,Thank you thats what i wanted , you are a god :)